# Retrieving documents for MongoDB cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve all the documents from a MongoDB cluster. I have followed code I've seen online, however I am facing a small problem.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-10soy.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
var questionsArray = [];

MongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, client) {


    const database = client.db("WhatSportWereYouMadeFor");
    database.collection("Questions").find({}, (error, cursor) =>{
        cursor.each(function(error, item){
            if (item == null){
                console.log(error);
            }
            questionsArray.push(item);
        });
    })
});


module.exports = { questionsArray };
```

I connect fine to the database, however I've set a breakpoint at the stop variable and that gets hit before any of the documents retrieved from the database get pushed to the questions array.
I've also tried wrapping the code inside an async function and then awaiting it before the stop variable, but still that breakpoint gets hit first and only after the documents get pushed to the array.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, this wrap the whole thing into a promise, and the export that.

```js
const MyExport = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var questionsArray = [];
    MongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, client) {
      const database = client.db("WhatSportWereYouMadeFor");
        database.collection("Questions").find({}, (error, cursor) =>{
          cursor.each(function(error, item){
            if (item == null){
                console.log(error);
            }
            questionsArray.push(item);
        });
      resolve(questionsArray)
     })
   });
  })
}

module.exports.questionsArray = MyExport
```

But then when you import it, you need to run and await it

```js
cosnt questionsArrayFunc = require("path/to/this/file").questionsArray
const questionsArray = await questionsArrayFunc()
```

I hope this is what you looking for. There might be some other way, but I think this works.

Comment: Please have a look again at the post, I've edited it with the latest changes. The module.exports line still gets hit before the items get pushed to the array, I'm not sure how to wait for that.